# Transparent error bars without affecting markers

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, errorbar

Is it possible to change the transparency of just the error bars? When using `plt.errorbar()` changing alpha affects both the markers and the error bars.

**EDIT:**

In my case, I have several different sets of data, and each value has its own error, so I plot each data set using `plt.errorbar()`. Here is a MWE using 3 different data sets:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = [np.random.uniform(0,10,5)]
x2 = [np.random.uniform(0,10,5)]
x3 = [np.random.uniform(0,10,5)]
y1 = [np.random.uniform(0,10,5)]
y2 = [np.random.uniform(0,10,5)]
y3 = [np.random.uniform(0,10,5)]
err1 = [np.random.uniform(1,2, 5)]
err2 = [np.random.uniform(1,2, 5)]
err3 = [np.random.uniform(1,2, 5)]

plt.errorbar(x1, y1, xerr=err1, yerr=err1, fmt='ro', ms=10)
plt.errorbar(x2, y2, xerr=err2, yerr=err2, fmt='bs', ms=10)
plt.errorbar(x3, y3, xerr=err3, yerr=err3, fmt='g^', ms=10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be done by examining what is returned when calling `plt.errorbar()`. Looking at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) it returns a

> plotline : Line2D instance
>
> x, y plot markers and/or line
>
> caplines : list of Line2D instances
>
> error bar cap
>
> barlinecols : list of LineCollection
>
> horizontal and vertical error ranges

Each of these can be modified used `set_alpha()`. So, to avoid changing the transparency of the markers, don't change `plotline`.

A full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.1, 4, 0.5)
y = np.exp(-x)

# example variable error bar values
yerr = 0.1 + 0.2*np.sqrt(x)
xerr = 0.1 + yerr

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
markers, caps, bars = ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
            fmt='o', ecolor='black',capsize=2, capthick=2)

# loop through bars and caps and set the alpha value
[bar.set_alpha(0.5) for bar in bars]
[cap.set_alpha(0.5) for cap in caps]

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

**Update**: A possible solution when dealing with multiple lists of data (apart from simply repeating the above code x amount of time) would be to put things (such as x values, y values etc.) in another list, then loop through these, meaning you don't have to manually code this. Using your edited example:

```
# Put all your data into other lists
x_list = [x1, x2, x3]
y_list = [y1, y2, y3]
err_list = [err1, err2, err3]
formats = ['ro', 'bs', 'g^']

# Loop through data and plot
for x, y, err, f in zip(x_list, y_list, err_list, formats):
    markers, caps, bars = plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=err, yerr=err, fmt=f, ms=10)
    [bar.set_alpha(0.5) for bar in bars]
    [cap.set_alpha(0.5) for cap in caps]

plt.show()
```

Which for the example gives:

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant. But how can I do it if I have around 30 sets of data plotted individually? I mean in order of not to have to do e.g. bars1, bars2, ... bars30. I'll try appending into bars = [ ]. Do you have another idea?

Comment: It depends on how you are plotting the data as to which would be the best way. There willl be a better way than putting everything into a list but its hard to say currently. Can you update your question, preferrably with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I  have edited my question, I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. In your real code, have you manually created all your data. i.e. have you written `x1 = [np.random.uniform(0,10,5)]` 30 times? Or is there some sort of loop that you are using?

Comment: I have my data on one file and I have created several (~30) filters manually for the same data. Perhaps I could have plot it with a loop but it wasn't that simple since I use different colors, markers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is using the RGBA color format (**R**ed,**G**reen,**B**lue,**A**lpha) when defining the parameter `ecolor`.

If you want to use a color based on its name you may use the function `matplotlib.colors.to_rgba` ([see documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html#matplotlib.colors.to_rgba)) for an easy conversion.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

x = range(5)
y = (0,-0.5,0.1,0.5,1)
err = 2.0

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3,)
for ax, color in zip(axs,('red',[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.5],colors.to_rgba('red',0.5))):
    ax.set_title(color)
    ax.errorbar(x,y,fmt='o',
                yerr=err,xerr=err,
                ecolor=color)
```

[image: subplots with transparent errorbar using RGBA]